# How to read response using webrequest

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get response from page using WebRequest.

But my code returns only source code without my values.

Code:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.jigar.net/demo/httprequestdemoclient.aspx")
Dim postData As String = "text1=hello"
Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)
request.KeepAlive = True
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.ContentLength = data.Length
Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
End Using
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim responseString As String = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
MsgBox(responseString)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "source code without my values"?  What specifically does `responseString` contain?  What do you expect it to contain?

Comment: Well, the responsestring contains only page source code. I expected same code with few lines extra (postdata). Just like when you visit that page, fill inputs and click on post.

Comment: What "extra lines" did you expect?  Be specific.  It's not really clear what the actual problem is.  A response from a web server *would be* the code to render the page.

Comment: ResponseString is missing <hr/>field1 : hello</br>field2 :</br>

Comment: Ok, and why exactly do you *expect* that to be in the response?  This sounds like something you should take up with whoever maintains that server.  If they're returning unexpected responses, there's little *we* can do about that.  If you can demonstrate specifically why that value *should* be there, we might be able to help with that.

Comment: When you visit that page in code, try to fill inputs a click on post. I only want to get modifed source code of that page using HttpWebRequest. Tried many ways but no progress.

Answer (score 0):

On the link you're using there are more form fields.  You're sending one, but I count six:

- Text1
- Text2
- ctl01
- __VIEWSTATE
- __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
- __EVENTVALIDATION

Debugging this for a moment, if I send values for just the first two then I get a response similar to what you describe.  However, if I send all six values, I get the response you're expecting.

It would appear that your process should involve a couple of steps:

1. Make a GET request to the URL
2. Parse the additional form values that the server expects to get back (everything above except for `Text1` and `Text2`)
3. Include those 4 additional key/value pairs in your POST request

Basically, this website appears to be using hidden form values to "validate" the POST request, ensuring that it's coming from a valid use of the page and not an automated request.  (Basically, to make it *slightly harder* to do exactly what you're trying to do.)  You'd have to make a GET request first to fetch those values and use them in your POST request.